# Galleriffic plugin issues with IE7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm using the Galleriffic plugin for a custom slideshow gallery. It works wonderfully in every major browser (IE 8, Firefox 3.6.x, Safari and Chrome) except for IE 7.

It does the weirdest thing in IE 7, it won't display the image, the div is being displayed but the image isn't being loaded into it. Both ways of linking the images still won't bring it in (full link as in: http://www.google.com/logos/2010/xraydiscovery2010-ps.gif and local link as in: images/slideshow/image1.jpg).

Has anyone experienced this issue and can give some guidance on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Galleriffic CSS being used: http://pastebin.com/z80QugaE -

Display code being used: http://pastebin.com/gA6gjWYY -

jQuery Call: http://pastebin.com/gWm0F6PH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with a CSS property.

When resizing the image display window it would push the image down below it in IE7, so the issue was with the default CSS in 'div.slideshow img'

Had to add `position: absolute;` and `left: 0;` to fix the issue.