# jQuery Galleriffic plugin hiding images in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

Has anyone resolved the Galleriffic IE7 issue? I noticed a few questions posted in the past on this topic.  I have tried absolutely everything and have had no luck... The main images are hidden for some reason, only in IE7, anyone have a clue why?

Answer (score 1):

Issue was with a CSS property.

When resizing the image display window it would push the image down below it in IE7, so the issue was with the default CSS in `div.slideshow img`.

Had to add `position: absolute;` and `left: 0;` to fix the issue.

Reference:
[Galleriffic plugin issues with IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126119/galleriffic-plugin-issues-with-ie7)